# Configuring Spring Cloud Vault Config to pull from a location other than /secret

Tags: spring-cloud, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I am currently integrating [Spring Cloud Vault Config](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/) into a Spring Boot application. From the home page:

> Spring Cloud Vault Config reads config properties from Vaults using the application name and active profiles:

```
/secret/{application}/{profile}
/secret/{application}
/secret/{default-context}/{profile}
/secret/{default-context}
```

I would like to instead provide my own location from which to pull properties from Vault which does not start with /secret (e.g. /deployments/prod). I've been looking through the reference documentation but I haven't found anyway to specify this -- is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be done this way.

#### Have a Configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class VaultConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public VaultConfigurer configurer() {
        return new VaultConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addSecretBackends(SecretBackendConfigurer configurer) {
                configurer.add("secret/my-app/path-1");
                configurer.add("secret/my-app/path-2");

                configurer.registerDefaultGenericSecretBackends(false);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This way you can scan your secrets placed in custom path

Regards
Arun

Answer (score 5):

I was able to use the [Generic Backend](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/1.0.1.RELEASE/#vault.config.backends.generic) properties to massage the paths into what I was looking for. Something like:

```
spring.cloud.vault:
    generic:
        enabled: true
        backend: deployments
        profile-separator: '/'
        default-context: prod
        application-name: my-app
```

This will also unfortunately pickup Vault locations like `deployments/my-app` and `deployments/prod/activeProfile` so be careful not to have any properties in these locations that you don't want to be picked up.

It looks like there is a [desire (and an implementation)](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/pull/57) to allow for these paths to be specified more programmatically.

Comment: You might be interested in [`VaultConfigurer`](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/spring-cloud-vault.html#vault.config.backends.configurer), available since today on `master`.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same problem in my `Kotlin` project. But it works in Java too.

#### Problem

I wanted to specify vault paths in yaml config, so i ended up with the following solution, that allows you to specify paths directly in `bootstrap.yml` using clear syntax, as:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    vault:
      paths: "secret/your-app"
```

#### Solution:

1. Create `VaultConfig` class in your project, with the following content:

```kotlin
package com.your.app.configuration

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty
import org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultConfigurer
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(
    prefix = "spring.cloud.vault", value = ["paths"],
    matchIfMissing = false
)
class VaultConfig {

    @Value("\${spring.cloud.vault.paths}")
    private lateinit var paths: List<String>

    @Bean
    fun configurer(): VaultConfigurer {
        return VaultConfigurer { configurer ->
            paths.forEach {
                configurer.add(it)
            }
            configurer.registerDefaultGenericSecretBackends(false)
            configurer.registerDefaultDiscoveredSecretBackends(false)
        }
    }
}
```

2. Create `spring.factories` file in `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` with a content:

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=com.your.app.configuration.VaultConfig
```

> Don't forget to specify valid reference to your config instead of
> `com.your.app.configuration.VaultConfig`
>
> `spring.factories` allows your VaultConfig
>
> happen in the bootstrap context, [as documentation says](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/html/#vault.config.backends.configurer).

3. Now you can specify desired paths in your `bootstrap.yml`, as follows:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    vault:
      paths: 
        - "secret/application"
        - "secret/your-app"
```

And it should work.