# How can I use SpringBoot to pick up DB credentials from Vault?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I have a `springboot` app that uses these versions:

```
SpringBoot: 2.3.1
SpringCloud: Hoxton.SR5 
SpringData: Neumann-SR1
```

I've used the custom class as described here (answer from @Arun): [Configuring Spring Cloud Vault Config to pull from a location other than /secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983688/configuring-spring-cloud-vault-config-to-pull-from-a-location-other-than-secret)

It doesn't even seem to be picking up the vault configs.
I have a `bootstrap.yml` with the following:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    # Vault configurations
    vault:
      generic:
        enabled: false
      uri: https://${URI}
      authentication: TOKEN
      token: ${VAULT_TOKEN}

    config:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
```

I'm trying to bring it up locally, so I have my `application.yml` as follows:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8157/postgres
```

This is where I'm trying to inject the values from `vault` into my DataSource:

```
@Profile(value = {"local", "dev", "stg", "prd"})
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

  @Autowired
  DatabaseCredentials config;

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DataSource dataSource() {

    return DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
        .username(config.getUsername())
        .url(config.getUrl())
        .password(config.getPassword())
        .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
        .build();
  }
}
```

When the app starts up, it `DatabaseCredentials` is empty.

The other way I've done it is like this:

```
public class DatabaseConfig {
  
  @Value("${ccm.database.username}")
  String username;

  @Value("${ccm.database.password}")
  String password;

  @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
  String url;

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    
    return DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
        .username(username)
        .url(url)
        .password(password)
        .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
        .build();
  }
}
```

This has also come up empty saying it can't find a value for `ccm.database.username`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like the path for the credentials in vault is missing in your bootstrap.yml

Comment: yea, was trying to use a custom `VaultConfigurer` as defined in the mentioned SO post, instead of defining it in bootstrap. ended up defining a `kv` backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Cloud Vault gives you DEBUG info which helped me figure out the issue. I ended up defining the path with `kv` instead of a custom `VaultConfigurer` bean.

```
kv:
  enabled: true
  backend: tcds/kv/app-name
  application-name: ccm
```

This creates the path as follows: `tcds/kv/app-name/ccm/${PROFILE}`.
I assumed that all secrets underneath this path will be picked up and I originally had multiple *folders* underneath my path of `tcds/kv/app-name/ccm/dev`.
For example: `../ccm/dev/database`, `../ccm/dev/other-creds`.

However, it seems that spring vault wasn't going to the nested paths for secrets and was looking for a *file* with all credentials there.

So, I removed the `dev` *folder* and replaced it with a `dev` *file* with entries such as:

```
{
  "database.username": "blah",
  "database.password": "moreblah",
  "other-creds.user": "dummy"
}
```

I am able to get credentials from vault by using the `DatabaseConfig.java` class alone and not having to use `DatabaseCredentials.java` with the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the annotations on `DatabaseConfig.java`

Which will be something like this.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("ccm.database")
```

So it becomes

```
@ConfigurationProperties("ccm.database")
@Component
public class DatabaseCredentials {
  
  @Value("${ccm.database.username}")
  String username;

  @Value("${ccm.database.password}")
  String password;

  @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
  String url;

  // Getters and setters for all properties go here
}
```

To access the config

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

  @Autowired
  DatabaseCredentials config;

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DataSource dataSource() {

    return DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
        .username(config.getUsername())
        .url(config.getUrl())
        .password(config.getPassword())
        .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
        .build();
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried `@ConfigurationProperties` directly on the `DatabaseConfig.java` class as well as `DatabaseCredentials.java` class, which I then use as shown in my OP above (autowire, then `config.username`). Neither have worked. I get this back as the error: ```2020-07-06 17:25:46,482 DEBUG pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Failed to create/setup connection: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "username"
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, but that's what I had. In fact, the example you provided is what I have in the original Post. But as I said there, when the app starts up, it `DatabaseCredentials` is empty.

Comment: It is not exactly the same

Comment: I have two versions of the `DatabaseConfig.java` class listed above. I'm sorry, other the the `@Profile..` tag, I fail to see what's different in my first version.

Answer (score 0):

Spring cloud supports import standart spring boot configuration from vault.

use two dependendences for automatic configuration:

- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-vault-config
- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-vault-config-databases

See:
https://medium.com/digitalfrontiers/manage-your-database-accounts-with-spring-cloud-vault-config-48cecb837a36